# How to change visual behavior of a button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, windows-10

I noticed that on Windows 10, the appearance of controls shown by the OS looks much more appealing than the defaults on Winforms/WPF. For example, The selected OS button has a thicker blue border, and a more interactive "feel" to it, while the default WPF button appears as a simple grey box:

OS:
[image]

WPF:
[image]

Is there a way to somehow change the "theme" of a button in WPF to behave similarly to the most OS-displayed buttons, without having to implement this behaviour manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get similar button styles using Windows UWP.

In WPF, you can check out the [Modern UI(MUI)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31) in MSDN site.

It can produce similar results. I have been working with mui for a couple of months and it really helped me to satisfy my client who wanted to have a Windows 10 like UI experience. I had to create tiles like in start menu also. MUI did a great job for me.

Get the MUI from Github. [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)

Also I had tried [devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/) and [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx) controls. Have a look at them too.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do it in native Windows 10, without external libraries?

Comment: I have an already built WPF form, is it possible to achieve the same result without re-creating it?

Comment: Yes obviously, you can have a mix of native controls as well as third party controls at the same time without recreating it. If you want to create without using external libraries, then consider creating a custom button and define the style manually, which maybe time consuming and hectic. That's why developers prefer third party controls.

Comment: It's okay. It's not only about gaining correct answers or reputation, but all about sharing information and learning. :) Glad that I could pass some of my knowledge to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**DevExpress**](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/) to get [themes](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2008/07/15/how-to-add-themes-skins-to-your-asp-net-website.aspx) for your form. Or you can implement your own by adding borders around every button and change its Color/Visibility on MouseDown and MouseUp event handlers

Answer (score 1):

Define a Style within Window.Resources with TargetType="Button" so that it affects all the buttons in that window. For example, although the default WPF button has mouseover colour change and a focus rectangle, it does not move "inwards" on MouseDown, so this example shows how to do this:

```
<Window.Resources>              
    <!--A Style that affects all Buttons-->         
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property= "RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.99" ScaleY="0.99"/>
                            <TranslateTransform  X="2" Y="2"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Thickness Left="2" Right="2" Top="2" Bottom="2"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Insert this after the Window attributes and before the Grid or other container tag.